# Typescript Inerfaces Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am trying to add Type Assertion to the object, I am facing a TypeError during assigning a value to the nested object.

Here is snippet

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string;
    study: {
        schoolName: string
    }
}

let john = {} as Person;

john.age = 25;
john.name = 'John';
john.study.schoolName = 'some school';

console.log(john); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'schoolName' of undefined
```

Link for the Typescript playground [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20study%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schoolName%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20john%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Person%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ajohn.age%20%3D%2025%3B%0D%0Ajohn.name%20%3D%20'John'%3B%0D%0Ajohn.study.schoolName%20%3D%20'some%20school'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(john)%3B)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking at the [compiled version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20study%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schoolName%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20john%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Person%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ajohn.age%20%3D%2025%3B%0D%0Ajohn.name%20%3D%20'John'%3B%0D%0Ajohn.study.schoolName%20%3D%20'some%20school'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(john)%3B) of your snippet will clear it out for you

```
var john = {};
john.age = 25;
john.name = 'John';
john.study.schoolName = 'some school';
console.log(john);
```

As you see Typescript does not actually initialize the study property.

Comment: Yeah, It was clear but I thought maybe there are some trick or something

Answer (score 0):

Because interface doesn't actually "create" your object.
In your code before you start assigning values john is just empty object. You can assign properties to it (age, name,...), because that is something normal.
You are trying to assign a property to an object property that doesn't exist. Either use class and initialize it using a constructor. Or have a function that creates objects from that "interface" correctly.

Basically interface is just a fancy thing in typescript to prevent typos, etc from developers. It doesn't create anything behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already searched and found the same solution as you said. But I am trying to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript will only tell your IDE what types this new object has. It will not create a full object for you.

Here is how you want to create the object:

```
interface Person {
    age: number;
    name: string;
    study: {
        schoolName: string
    }
}

let john = {} as Person;

john.age = 25;
john.name = 'John';
john.study = { 
    schoolName: 'some school'
};

console.log(john);
```

alternatively you can directly do this:

```
let john: Person = {
    age: 25;
    name: 'John';
    study: {
        schoolName: 'some school'
    }
};
```